# Create a popup message asking a Yes or No question in GWT

Tags: gwt

I want a popup window asking the user to a yes or no question when he click a button.

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
     deleteUser();
}//this lets user to delete a certain user when they click a button, but there is no question asking if they really want to delete this user.
```

I want a new small popup window (such as JFrame in Java Swing) asking `Are you sure you want to delete this user?` with a `Yes` or `No` button.

I'm developing in GWT.

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Apart from implementing a dialog with PopupPanel, I guess the best you can get is Window.confirm() (from com.google.gwt.user.client).